# Equivalance relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wonder if there is something more general than the concept of the equivalance relation and in general the concept of relations .Any thoughts of how such a generalization is?

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of generalization are you looking for?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar ,any kind:)if you cannot describe all the kinds at once then give me some examples.thank you

Comment: To me, it seems like an equivalence relation is as general as can get, so I'm sorry that I can't be of much help here.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar thank you for your time:)

Comment: Yes; there is the concept of *set*; a *relation* is a particular type of set, i.e. a set of *ordered couples*. An *equivalence relation*, in turn, is a particular type of relation: a relation such that ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thank you. One more thing. I might be wrong but,isn't a class,which is generated by equivalance relations, more general than the concept of set? If yes or no, could you tell me a generalization of the concept of set or class if there is and if you know?:)

Comment: Yes; in some version of set theory, a *class* is more general than a *set*, because a set is a class that is member or subset of another class. But we have to stop somewhere...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA,haha. you never know thought.in some years maybe we will need a generalization and someone will find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may start from [classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) and we may refer to [Von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_axioms) :

> In the *foundations of mathematics*, **von Neumann–Bernays–Gödel** set theory ($\mathsf {NBG}$) is an axiomatic set theory that is a conservative extension of the canonical axiomatic set theory $\mathsf {ZFC}$.
>
> The ontology of $\mathsf {NBG}$ includes proper *classes*, objects having members but that cannot be members of other entities.

In this theory, *sets* are classes that are members or subsets of other classes.

A [*relation*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Set_Theory/Relations) in set theory is a special type of set :

> The simplest definition of a binary relation is a set of ordered pairs.

A [*function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a special type of relation, as well as an [*equivalence relation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

But we may start also from another point of view, using [Category theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) :

> Category theory is used to formalize mathematics and its concepts as a collection of *objects* and *arrows*.